# jquery fadein() works, but fadeout() does not

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

This is driving me batty... this works fine:

```
<div style="display:none" id="box">
    <img src="/images/wpgen_box1.jpg">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#box').fadein(); }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

But this does NOT work:

```
<div id="box"> 
    <img src="/images/wpgen_box1.jpg">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#box').fadeout(); }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

So, anyone know why I can fade in but not out?

Comment: There's a Highlander joke in here somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how `fadein` works actually. it is supposed to be `fade*I*n`, same for `fadeOut`.

Comment: OMG!  SERIOUSLY!?!??!  That fixed it.  Unbef---ingleivable.  Thanks!!