# Using PHP, edit or change the user agent before redirecting?

Tags: php, javascript, user-agent

I'm redirecting traffic to another website, but they have some filtering in place that is rejecting a portion of the traffic.  From what I understand, they're parsing the user agent string and refusing certain browsers.  I'd like to be able to filter the UAs on my side first and replace them as needed before redirecting them.

So far I have tried this:

```
ini_set('user_agent', "my user agent");
```

but it doesn't seem to actually change anything when the redirection occurs.

Is it possible to even do this?  Is it more of a Javascript thing since the UA is set in the browser?

I appreciate any ideas... thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how redirects work. The remote server will still get the user agent from the client's machine. Setting your own user agent would be applicable if your server was making a cURL request - then it is acting as the client.

Comment: Yeah I specifically can't use cURL because then the traffic originates from my server's IP which will screw everything up for tracking & such.  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: I wasn't suggesting using cURL. I was simply stating when setting the user agent would be applicable.

Comment: Yeah I realize that, was just clarifying that cURL isn't an option for me though I'd like to accomplish a similar end-result.  Sounds like I'm just SOL though.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot influence a browser's user agent setting from within a php script. I also doubt, that it is possible using JavaScript. However, what you might do is set up a proxy php script, which performs the requests to the remote site from your server and set the user agent of your script according to what you already tried (using ini_set).

Comment: I can't think of any way to accomplish this without using cURL though, which would mean the requests all come from my server which will cause all manner pf problems.  Any ideas on how I can do this and yet still have the request come from the original client's browser/IP/etc.?

Comment: Right. You cannot change a client setting from a server and then send the client to another server. From a security point of view, this is a good thing.

Comment: Yep very true, it just happens to throw a wrench in what we're doing.  Oh well... I'll talk with the owners of the other site and see if there's a way for them to relax their filters for us or something.

Comment: @Jonathan If your talking to the other site's admins, tell them that they are idiots for attempting to enforce a `User-Agent:` based blocking policy. To prove the point I posted this comment from IE, but all the site's logs will say I did it from Chrome. `User-Agent`-based blocking is definitely in the running for the most pointless approach to security available on the modern internet. On a more helpful note, please accept the answer to  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015929) of yours that has an acceptable answer, to ensure you keep getting them.

Comment: Ah thanks for that, at the time I got the answer it wouldn't let me choose one as correct, but have done so now.  And yeah I know it's stupid to determine who you should and shouldn't allow into your site by UA but... it is what it is.  It's stupid to do lots of other things too but I can't get people to stop them either.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

the other website is probably parsing the header which the users browser is submitting.
therefore it isn't posible to change the user agent

Comment: Yep that's my assumption.  Damn... was hoping maybe someone had a clever solution!